# jQuery thumbnail replace method (Needs solution for adding A tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a thumbnail replace solution, I need to add an a tag around an img item and still have the same functionality.

**The jQuery**

```
$(".large").click(function () {
    var thumbRel = $(this).attr("rel");
    $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".thumbnail img[rel='" + thumbRel + "']") }, 1000);
});

$(".thumb").click(function () {
    $(".thumbnail [class^='thumb']").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    $(".large").attr("rel", $(this).attr("rel"));

    $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $(".large") }, 1000);
    $(".large").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
    $(this).queue(function () {
        $(".large").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("-thumb", ""));

        $(".large").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

The markup is mixed with Dot Net, but here it is

```
<div class="product_images">        
    <div class="mainImage">            
        <a class="ShowProductImageDlg" href="#" onclick="ProductImagesDlgClientSide.showDialog('@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.UrlSlug', 'Bottle'); return false;" >
            <img class="LargeImage" src="@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.awsImageUrlLarge" alt="@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.ProductName" />
        </a>            
    </div>
    <strong>Additional Images</strong>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><img class="SmallImage Bottle" src="@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.awsImageUrlSmall" 
                    alt="@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.ProductName" /></a></li>                

            <li><a href=""><img class="SmallImage BackLabel" src="@Model.ProductToDisplay.ProductAdditionalImageUrlSmall(awsProductImageType.BackLabel)"
                    alt="@Model.ProductToDisplay.Product.ProductName" /></a></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

The end goal, is to have the entire div that the image is in clickable (which is 90px by 90px) when the image itself is only 80x35.

I want to use the same jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like that ([see jsfiddle as a proof](http://jsfiddle.net/vYyuZ/)):

```
var link = jQuery('<a>', {
    'href': 'http://www.google.com/',
    'title': 'Dynamically generated link'
});

jQuery('img').wrap(link);
```

Basically you first **create a link** (`<a>` element) and then **wrap it around the images** selected by the `img` selector (you can adjust it to your needs).

Comment: Sorry,

I just need the <a href="#"> so I can put display: block on the element to make the entire box clickable. (90x90px) and the images are 80x35 

I don't want the thumbnails to link anywhere.

Comment: So just apply `display: block; cursor: pointer;` to the images, and add padding to them. There's no point creating elements for wrapping purposes for no reason than presentation.

Comment: @rc89: You do not need `<a>` tags to wrap around images to make them clickable, you do not even need them to apply `display: block;`, even the pointer can be changed. I think it is a good time to think your idea over.

Comment: Thanks guys, adding the cursor pointer, removing the text-align: center and adding padding helped.

Comment: That being said, Ive been doing some testing and found the images are different sizes so the padding option won't work.

Comment: @rc89: Sorry to say that, but you are wrong - depending on what _exactly_ you want to achieve, there multiple possibilities to achieve similar effects. HTML+CSS+JS trio is very flexible and allows you to change the way something is displayed even with minimum HTML. The HTML should have only semantic content, the presentation should be done only in CSS.

Comment: @Tadeck I'm using set width 90x90px boxes, Some images are 15px some are 35px others are 80px wide (adding the padding to the img element would push them outside of the box) especially if I'm using 30px from the left to accomodate for smaller images.

Comment: @rc89: In that case you may need something less basic. Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EKFY/) and tell me if that is what you expected. I will update my answer.